# Testing IPP Printing with ipptool

Tags: printer, printing, network-printer, cups

I'm trying to send an IPP print job using the [ipptool](http://www.cups.org/software.php). Using the sample .test files, I can send commands to the printer, but I am unable to successfully use the print-job.test file.

Here's an example using ipptool.

```
c:\...>ipptool -v ipp://name.local.:631/ipp/printer print-job.test
ipptool: Filename "$filename" on line 21 cannot be read.
ipptool: Filename mapped to "".
```

It looks like it's failing resolving the variable $filename within the test file so I attempted to hardcode this value in the test file. In this case I get no error, but still no print.

Does anybody have any experience using ipptool to test ipp printing?

Answer (score 2):

Edit a copy of your `print-job.test` file and save it as `senloe---print-job.test`.

Your edit should replace the variables in the following two lines with hard-coded values:

```
ATTR mimeMediaType document-format $filetype
FILE $filename
```

Replace them, for example with:

```
ATTR mimeMediaType document-format text/plain
FILE senloe---print-job.test
```

This should send your file `senloe---print-job.test` as a plain text file to printers.

You'll need to use the following command line (assuming you have CUPS installed locally):

```
ipptool -v -t ipp://localhost:631/printers/your-real-printername \
       ./senloe---print-job.test
```

You should see something like the following output:

```
"./senloe---print-job.test":
   Print-Job:
       attributes-charset (charset) = utf-8
       attributes-natural-language (naturalLanguage) = en
       printer-uri (uri) = ipp://localhost:631/printers/ubuquitech
       requesting-user-name (nameWithoutLanguage) = senloe
       document-format (mimeMediaType) = text/plain
       copies (integer) = 1
   Print file using Print-Job                                      [PASS]
       RECEIVED: 171 bytes in response
       status-code = successful-ok (successful-ok)
       attributes-charset (charset) = utf-8
       attributes-natural-language (naturalLanguage) = en
       job-uri (uri) = ipp://localhost:631/jobs/24
       job-id (integer) = 24
       job-state (enum) = pending
       job-state-reasons (keyword) = none
```

If this works, the following should also work, now using the original test file `print-job.test` (which contains the variables) again, and using your edited `senloe---print-job.test` as the file to be printed:

```
ipptool -v -t -f senloe---print-job.test                  \
       ipp://localhost:631/printers/your-real-printername \
       ./print-job.test
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this line:

```
c:\...>ipptool -vt -f [name of your URF file] ipp://name.local.:631/ipp/printer print-job.test
```

and have the URF file in the same location as your `.test` file. Also, it is recommended to have the `ipptool` in the same location as well.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I created an *AppImage* of the *[IPP Sample Software](https://github.com/istopwg/ippsample)* which now includes not only ***`ipptool`***, but also `ippserver` which can emulate a virtual IPP Printer in your local network.

- To download, visit: https://github.com/KurtPfeifle/ippsample/releases
- Here is the direct link to the IPP Sample Software [AppImage](https://github.com/KurtPfeifle/ippsample/releases/download/continuous/ippsample-x86_64.AppImage)

(What's an AppImage? That is the package of a software consisting of multiple files -- even multiple different tools, apps or utilities -- ***bundled into a single compressed file***. Just make it executable and run it from any location, on any Linux x86_64 distro.)

I also created an ASCIInema movie which demonstrates the usage of the ippsample bundle and the usage of *`ipptool`*:

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 0):

```
ipptool -v -tf /path/to/your.pdf  -d filetype=application/octet-stream -I http://printer-url/ipp /usr/share/cups/ipptool/print-job.test
```

Comment: You could add some explanations.